# React.js/ScrollMagic mount component after DOM modification

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use ScrollMagic with React and I'm stuck with the setPin() function which wraps my component within a div. As the component in mounted before the wrapping, everytime I update my states or props, React seems to think that the component doesn't exist and mount it again.

How can I manage to mount my component after the setPin function which does the wrapping?

```
  componentDidMount () {
    this.scrollController = new ScrollMagic.Controller()
    this.initScroller()
  }

  initScroller () {
    this.scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: this.node,
      duration: window.innerHeight * 2,
      triggerHook: 0,
      reverse: true
    })
    this.scene.setPin(this.node, { pushFollowers: false })
    this.scrollController.addScene(this.scene)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div
        ref={node => {
          this.node = node
        }}
      >
        <div className={this.getClassNames()}>
          <Hemicycle
            deputiesCount={this.props.deputiesCount}
            swissCount={this.props.swissCount}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: perhaps you should consider wrapping the parts of your app which you don't want to be affected by props and state changes with [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate), and by this prevent them from getting re-rendered..

Comment: The problem is that shouldComponentUpdate does not prevent my component to be mounted. It certainly prevents the component to be updated but it is still mounted. I think that as the component as been wrapped in a div, when React render the components, after a state/prop change, it doesn’t find the component where it should be and thinks it’s missing so it mounts it again. Because the componentDidMount is triggered several times.

Comment: [I tried reproducing](https://codesandbox.io/s/92rrn26w54) but couldn't :/ 
Seems to be working fine. You can see that in [the example](https://codesandbox.io/s/92rrn26w54) the input updates the state which updates the nested "pinned component" - and nothing breaks..

Comment: Actually it’s working fine until I make a dist version using webpack... I have no clue what’s going on. Once packed, everytime the component is pined, it remounts, duplicating itself.